# SQL: Use count from two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

How to construct a query for the following scenario:

I have three tables:

1. People
2. Books (linked with people on `peopleserno`)
3. Videos (linked with people on `peopleserno`)

I want to create an SQL where the output gives one row containing how many books & videos a specific person has read/watched.

Example output:

`John | 3 (books) | 2 (videos)`

I have tried things like this, but it doesn't work:

```
select a.name, 
       count(b.serno) as books, 
       count(c.serno) as videos
  from people a, 
       books b, 
       videos c
 where a.serno = b.peopleserno
   and a.serno = c.peopleserno
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `left join` to get even users that did not read/watch anything and then you need to `group by` the user to get specific user counts

```
select a.name, 
       count(distinct b.title) as books, 
       count(distinct c.title) as videos 
from people a
left join books b on a.serno = b.peopleserno
left join videos c on a.serno = c.peopleserno
group by a.name
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e366d/7)

Comment: @491243: You're right, I didn't. Fixed the error now. Thanks.

Comment: actually it will work if the column has identity set on it and you can count correctly, eg `COUNT(DISTINCT x.identityColumn)` `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to do the calculation in a subquery unless the table has auto_incremented column present on it. Assuming that the table has no auto_incremented column,

```
SELECT  a.Name,
        COALESCE(b.TotalBook, 0) TotalBook,
        COALESCE(c.TotalVideo, 0) TotalVideo
FROM    People a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  peopleserno, COUNT(*) TotalBook
            FROM    Books
            GROUP   BY peopleserno
        ) b ON a.serno = b.peopleserno
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  peopleserno, COUNT(*) TotalVideo
            FROM    Videos
            GROUP   BY peopleserno
        ) c ON a.serno = c.peopleserno
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da7e5/5)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a GROUP BY clause by the fields you need to agregate to count.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, 
       ( select count(b.serno) from books b where a.serno = b.peopleserno ) as books, 
       ( select  count(c.serno) from videos c where a.serno = c.peopleserno) as videos 
from people a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, 
       count(b.title)||' (books)'  as books, 
       count(c.title)||' (videos)'  as videos 
from people a
left join books b on a.serno = b.peopleserno
left join videos c on a.serno = c.peopleserno
group by a.name


OR

select a.name, 
       ( select count(b.serno) from books b where a.serno = b.peopleserno ) as books, 
       ( select  count(c.serno) from videos c where a.serno = c.peopleserno) as videos 
from people a
```